# Is there any way to run code-first migrations every time I run the project?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I want to get the latest version of database and insert some rows into database for testing every time the project runs. Is there any way to upgrade the database with the latest version of migrations without input command in package manager console?

I found this article,

[EF4.3 Configuration File Settings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-configuration-file-settings.aspx)

I know I can let the upgrade to the latest version by configure the context element of the file, but I don't know how to let the upgrade run every time when the project is running without input command.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Did you at lest tried the configuration mentioned in the linked article. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, I have. I know how to write the config file, but I think there should be some code to let the migrations run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of mentioned configuration is calling this code at the bootstrap of your application:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourContext, YourMigrationConfiguration>());
```